# JS await function with empty Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have a question, I somewhat understand how Promises work but I would like to wait for a function to finish even if it doesn't return anything. I have a similar code but it doesn't wait for b to finish before starting the extra steps on a.

For example in this case I want to create tables in a sqlite db, then load data and run some tests. The thing here is that it's starting to run the tests before finishing to load the data and the arrays created in the loadData method are coming empty. I would even prefer not to return those arrays but to always wait for this process to be completed before running tests.

```
async function initialize(){
    try{
        console.log("Beginning connection");
        db = await connectToDB();
        console.log(`Database: ${db}`)
        db.serialize(function() {
            console.log("Creating tables")
            db.run(queries.__parent_company);
            db.run(queries.parent_company);
            db.run(queries.__sales_rep);
            db.run(queries.sales_rep);
            db.run(queries.advertiser);
            console.log("Tables created");
        });
        let response = await loadData();
        console.log("Response", response)
        testData();
    }
    catch(e){
        throw e;
    }
}

function loadData() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("Beggning data insertion");
        try{
            let insertedAdvertisers = [];
            let insertedSales = [];
            let insertedCOmpanies = [];
            data.rows.forEach(async row => {
                let advertiser = await loadAdvertisers(row);
                let sale = await loadSalesRep(row);
                let company = await loadParentCompany(row);
                insertedAdvertisers.push(advertiser);
                insertedSales.push(sale);
                insertedCOmpanies.push(company);
                console.log("HERE", insertedAdvertisers, insertedSales, insertedCOmpanies)
            })
            resolve({insertedAdvertisers, insertedSales, insertedCOmpanies});
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(e);
            reject(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by wait to finish? What is this function doing?

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/62esk1hz/

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: The code provided works as expected (b executes before subsequent steps inside a). Example by @Barmar demonstrates that.
There is not enough information in the question to determine what your issue is. What are the extra steps in b? My guess is that some of your extra steps inside b lack the `await` keyword and hence the promise resolves prematurely.

Comment: `await` only does something useful when you await a promise that resolves/rejects when the underlying asynchronous operation is complete.  You haven't shown any code for a real asynchronous operation so we don't really know what the actual problem is.  But, if I were to hazard a guess, I'd say you're returning a promise that does not resolve when the underlying asynchronous operation is done, but instead resolves before the asynchronous operation is done.  The promise has to be connected to the asynchronous operation.

Comment: If the actual asynchronous operation doesn't have a promise already, then call `resolve` for the promise you created in the completion callback of the actual asynchronous operation.

Comment: I just updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Taking about Promises, I advice you to read about the event loop and how it works.

What happens in your code that  JS knows that this is a promise so it will move it to callback queue until it finishes and continues executing your code  and then push it to the stack to be executed.
so if you want to execute a certain logic after an async function finishes you need to provide it as a callback or use .then()

```
async function a() {
  b().then(()=>{
      // your code that you want to be executed after a finishes 
})
}
```

This image might illustrate what I'm trying to explain

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).